# Dirichlet Problem, upper half space

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is the Dirichlet problem

\begin{cases}
\Delta u = 0 \text{ in} \mathbb{R}^n_+ \\
u\vert_{\partial \mathbb{R}^n_+} = \varphi
\end{cases}

always solvable for arbitrary continuous and bounded $\varphi$? Do we have to impose some decaying behaviour on $\varphi$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, a solution is
$$
            u(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{y}{(x-x')^2+y^2}\varphi(x')dx',\;\;\; y > 0.
$$
This the Poisson representation. Such a solution is not unique because there are solutions of Laplace's equation in the upper half-plane that vanish on the real axis--namely $v(x,y)=y$. However, if you require $u$ to be bounded throughout, then the solution is unique. There is a Poisson solution for a half space of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, too, using the [Poisson kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel) (Wikipedia link.)